# Recreating the schedule in the image using HTML, CSS, or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The schedule I want to recreate
[image]

I need help creating a schedule using CSS, HTML, and Javascript. I'm having trouble aligning three blank table cells for the 7:00-8:00 time period with the cells on Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.

This is my code:

```
th {
  border: none;
  color: black; /* Text color */
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell1 {
  background-color: #006400; /* Green */
}

.cell1wd1 {
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 2px 4px; /* Adjust top and bottom padding */
  font-size: 10px; /* Adjust font size if needed */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text wrapping */
}

.cell2 {
  background-color: #ffbec8; /* Green */
}

.cell3 {
  background-color: #808080; /* Green */
}
```

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th class="cell1">Monday</th>
            <th class="cell2">Tuesday</th>
            <th class="cell3">Wednesday</th>
            <th class="cell1">Thursday</th>
            <th class="cell2">Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>7:00 - 8:00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>
            <td class="cell1">CMSC 132</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: If you are good at CSS, then I recommend you to use Tailwind CSS, which would put your code in one place.

Comment: Also provide the result which you are getting currently

Comment: I'm unsure if I could attach pictures in replies but I'll attach my link here linking to the image of the result I'm getting. As of now, it's currently not that organized since I'm just basically playing around with the code and doing trial & errors to find if there are ways to replicate it. Thanks in advance!

https://imgur.com/a/BCXImjF

Comment: Do you want the same design and preferences or it to be dynamic and change according to the data?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Just the same design and preferences will do. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: Would you like me to create this from scratch? You can understand from that code afterwards

Comment: Sure anything is okay and fine with me and apologies if I might give you a hard time but thanks a lot for helping! :)

Comment: Hey I've got this made in Tailwind CSS: [Preview](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cqOA6nzzWN)

Comment: Revised version with child row https://play.tailwindcss.com/cqOA6nzzWN

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the problem is.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}

tr:not(:last-child)>:first-child, thead th:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.mon, .thu {
  background-color: #006400;
  color: white;
}

.tue, .fri {
  background-color: #ffbec8;
}

.wed {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th class="mon">Monday</th>
            <th class="tue">Tuesday</th>
            <th class="wed">Wednesday</th>
            <th class="thu">Thursday</th>
            <th class="fri">Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>7:00</td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed">AAA</td>
            <td class="thu" rowspan="2">BBB</td>
            <td class="fri">CCC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:00</td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed">DDD</td>
            <td class="fri">EEE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:00</td>
            <td class="mon">CMSC 132</td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think there is a row inside row with a `rowspan` of `2`

Comment: Again, one thing left which I'm stuck at as well is that adding 2 rows in each row

Comment: This seems the closest https://play.tailwindcss.com/cqOA6nzzWN